# Looping through a dataframe using itertuples() and read the next line

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have a dataframe as below. And I can print the output as

```
2
4
6

import pandas as pd

data = [[1,2,'a'],[3,4,'b'],[5,6,'c']]
columns = ['a','b','c']

df = pd.DataFrame(data ,columns = ['a','b','c'])

for i in df.itertuples():
    print(i.b)
```

Now Imagine I need to print the next line value from starting row always.How can I do that.
Basically I need the output of only

```
4
6
```

How can I do it.

My approach is like below:

```
for i in df.itertuples():
   # here there should be a if function asking not to go for the last row (first row from upside down of the dataframe) 
     print((i+1).b)
```

Comment: Have you checked https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html ? Just index the dataframe `df.loc[1:,'b']`

Comment: That approach does not work my requirement,,Basically I need to go for every row and from that next line should be read.

Comment: Before doing that, you might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/9698684 . Iterating over a dataframe's rows, isn't a great idea, unless necessary. That's why indexing methods exist

Comment: Okay I might need to change whole program I just wrote,,will check how it goes well,,Thanks Mate